# How to play sound again without having to wait for it to fisnish javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, playback, replay

I made a button on my website. When you click on it, it plays a sound. When you click on it again, it first completes playing the sound then plays it again. I want it to play the sound again and leave the previous click. Here's my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var audio = new Audio('749a13_Ba_Dum_Tss_Sound_Effect.mp3');

    function play(){
    audio.play();
    }

    </script>


    <audio id="badumtssssound" autoplay preload="auto" autobuffer> 
    <source src="749a13_Ba_Dum_Tss_Sound_Effect.mp3">
    </audio>

    <a onClick="play();"><img src="play_button.png" /></a>
```

Comment: you need to set the position to 0 before you call audio.play()

Comment: I am a complete newbie to Javascript. Can you help me out and point out how I could do that?

Comment: replace "audio.play();" with "audio.position=0;audio.play();"